Optimizing Query for Distinct Key-Value Pairs in a JSONB Column with LATERAL
I have a table called objects with a jsonb column, and I'm trying to run a query to get distinct key-value pairs from the JSON data. Currently, I'm using the following query:
SELECT DISTINCT keys, values
FROM objects, LATERAL jsonb_each_text(tags) AS each(keys, values);

However, this query is relatively slow, and I'm wondering if there are ways to optimize it.
How can I speed up this query?
Is it possible to create an index on the result of the LATERAL jsonb_each_text(tags) function to improve performance?
Can we avoid using materialized view (ref: How to index on an array of jsonb objects to get distinct values)?

To improve speed you first have to know what the problem is and what your target is. Could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for this statement, in plain text. And tell us how fast it should be

Qualify  all columns. (I.e. table.column.)

You can set up a trigger that's updating a separate tally table, if you're rejecting the matview idea because you need this to be always up to date. That way you'll always have pre-computed keys, values and counts.

@Zegarek I’m open to using a tally table, but I’m curious about the performance implications. Which approach is more expensive in this case: maintaining a materialized view or using a tally table? Given that the objects table will have many writes (approximately every 5 minutes), can triggers efficiently handle this load without becoming a bottleneck?

That's not entirely apples to apples because matview is never up to date except right after a refresh, in which case it's just as expensive as a view/prepared statement. With a tally table you incur a tiny fraction of that cost on any DML on the primary table. It's non-zero, your RTT/latency/throughput will be affected but quite often it's almost imperceivable unless you were already approaching the limits of acceptable performance. Assemble a test setup, then stress test it with pgbench to see if it can sustain your target load.
